# crear SP en BD desde EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Se que desde Entity Framework se puede elaborar un modelo y en base a este modelo crear una BD en un Sistema de Gestión de Bases de Datos, pero en mi caso requiero que al momento de crear el modelo también pueda crear funciones que luego en base a este modelo se pueda crear una BD con sus Stored Procedures incluidos, eso se puede? como se hace?

Comment: que significa SGBD ? estas usando EF Code First o usas un edmx ?

Comment: sgbd=Sistema Gestor de Base de Datos, como oracle sqlserver etc
Estoy con EDMX, nunca use code first pero si es necesario puedo aprender (Si tienen algun enlace para aprenderlo es bievenido)

Comment: Hola?  Leandro? Alguien?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La unica opcion que conozco relacionado con un edmx es la generacion de un script que crea la db en base al modelo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero esta opcion `Generate Database Script from Model...` es bastante limitado.

Si quieres generar codigo que defina procedure en la base de datos vas a tener que implementar `migrations` y eso implica usar `Code First`

[Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Migrations si te permite generar codigo que defina la estructura de la db que puedes extender para crear otros elementos.